# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68: Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, csrf

I have been looking for answers around the net for 3 hours now, and have tried so many solutions but it did not work. 
I have tried: answers from [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16064)

But none of them worked

> **Solution 1:**

```
sudo rm -rf storage/framework/sessions/*
sudo php artisan cache:clear
```

> **Solution 2:**

Clearing my cache and cookies in my browser,  then running

`php artisan config:cache`
and 
`php artisan cache:clear`

> **Solution no. 3**

[image]

> **Solution no. 4**

[image]

> **Solution no.5**

I tried changing my `{{ csrf_field() }}` to `{!! csrf_field() !!}`

> **Solution no. 6**

I tried moving `Auth::routes();` on top of my web routes.

> **Solution no. 7**

[image]

> **Solution no. 8**

I have changed my code from:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
   {{ csrf_field() }}
```

to:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
    {!! Form::open([ 'route' => 'login', 
                     'method' => 'POST' ]) !!}
```

I even tried adding a `{{ csrf_field() }}` in `Form::open`

I even tried adding another bracket `{{{ csrf_field() }}}`

> **Solution no. 9**

Desperately restarting my server(MAMP) then clearing cache

There is another solution, which says that I should download a fresh install of Laravel, but I cannot do that because this is a big project.

---

Here is my `.env file`

```
API_DEBUG=true
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:g43UiAlu11L/y9ThUjiVqFi52/d2Jf/JHaPNwkwzU4o=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_KEY=
PUSHER_SECRET=

API_PREFIX=api
API_SUBTYPE=app
API_VERSION=v1

JWT_TTL=20160

SIGN_UP_RELEASE_TOKEN=false
PASSWORD_RESET_RELEASE_TOKEN=false

PAGINATION_ITEMS_PER_PAGE=10

# Database Connections

DB_CONNECTION=mysql-core
DB_CORE_HOST=localhost:8889
DB_CORE_PORT=3306
DB_CORE_DATABASE=core
DB_CORE_USERNAME=root
DB_CORE_PASSWORD=root
```

my `Kernel.php`

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'secure.requests',
    ],
```

in my `session.php`

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
```

Here's my `web.php`

```
<?php

Route::group([ 'middleware'  => [ 'secure.requests' ] ], function() {

    Auth::routes();

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

});
```

I am also using the laravel dubugbar 
[image]

It's a long post, but I am desperate to be able to solve this. I hope someone can help me.

> **EDIT:** I tried logging in from the API side (locally) and it works. the problem is just the web side.

Comment: just try with php artisan key:generate

Comment: @iCoders sadly no :(

Answer (score 1):

I found these steps from here:
[token mismatch](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftokenphp-line-68-on-some-device?page=1)

1). Remove 'SESSION_DRIVER' field from your .env
 2). Go to your config/session.php and in domain mark the second parameter of env() 
    to null i.e.

'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null)

3). Run php artisan cache:config and php artisan cache:clear 
  4). Restart the server and clear your browser cache, and whoaa may be all things are 
  up and running now.

Comment: This maybe a long shot, but go through your views and make sure you are calling any csrf_field() or csrf_token() only once per view.  In other words, clear out them all, and try systematically adding them in one by one.  You may be duplicating them some where.

Comment: @eibersji, were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not working, it seems only happen on specific shared hosting provider, move the same source to another provider, it's OK without any of above trick but still one shared hosting got error and no solution, tried all above, nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue once, try to run the command below from the project directory:

chmod 777 storage/framework/sessions/

I hope it will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`{{ csrf_field() }}` to

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" class="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```